# Good Way to verify RavenDB imported large amounts of data from SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql, ravendb

I'm using a console application to migrate large amounts of data from SQL Server to RavenDB.

What is the best way to verify the data in RavenDB was imported from SQL Server?

I tried to create lists of objects from RavenDB and compare it a list of the same object from Sql.

The problem I run into is that the data is too large to put all of it into a collection to compare even if I query for specific data.

I can only retrieve small amounts of data at a time from RavenDB (only a list of 128) directly in the console application.  I know that can be overridden on the server side, but that is something I can not do.  I thought perhaps an index could help me in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moyler,
You can page through the data and compare it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I was actually trying to do this before you answered, but was getting results that were slightly off while paging. I am sure it's something I'm doing with 'orderby' and linq.